# Is changing the source code on another website okay?

Tags: web

I’ve been messing around with source codes on websites recently (using Firefox), just to see what they mean and what they do, but I noticed that you can edit them and it changes whatever you want on the website. And all I wanna know is if that’s okay

Comment: sure this is fine.  You are only changing the code in your browser.

Comment: Oh sweet man, I appreciate it